# Hizzuk Emunah in Hebrew online

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, internet, christianity, non-rabbinic-judaism

*Hizzuk Emunah* ("Faith Strengthened") is a Jewish response to Christian missionaries, composed by Lithuanian Karaite scholar, [Isaac ben Abraham of Troki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_of_Troki).

I managed to find [an English version](https://jewsforjudaism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/FaithStrengthened.pdf) of this work via Jews for Judaism, however I would be interested in a Hebrew version, online.  Does anyone know where I could find this?

Comment: Um... How is asking for a copy of a Sefer published by Jews for Jews considered “comparative religion”?

Comment: @DonielF Probably because the author of said book is a Karaite. But I recall a Meta post about that

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1531/9682 https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4051/9682

Comment: FWIW There’s a thread on Christianity.SE that attempts to respond to this Sefer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/13862

Comment: Good Luck with finding a good Hebrew version, but, wow, that English version was a good read!  Lots of good stuff besides the usual countermissionary ammo.

Comment: @Gary The great thing about it being composed by a Karaite is that the arguments presented come strictly from the Tanach. This makes it especially useful when combating Christians.

Comment: That's part of it--one of my best friends is a Born-Again and we have  lots of "theological discussions", so new stuff is good to have...but the great part is that it's nearly 500 years old, and that guy had big enough cojones  to write it without getting roasted alive or tortured to death by either Christians or Muslims.  The 16th century wasn't a great place to be a Jew in lots of the world, never mind while writing stuff like that.

Comment: @Gary I love talking with you about things like this! If you ever feel like it, send me an email (you can find it in my contact page)

Comment: K  will be in touch...I don't use email much, but sure!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[HebrewBooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/32376) has a very old copy online.

Comment: Nice find, I think that version censors out all karaite sources,and leaves just the argument against the notzrim

Comment: @sam which makes sense why it's on hebrewbooks

Comment: Anything on Google Books?